# How to set position for dialog created via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

HTML:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Link</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
        if ($(this).hasClass('ui-dialog-titlebar-close')) return;
        event.preventDefault();        
        var data = '<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">';
            data += '<p>Hello.</p></div>';
        $(data).dialog();
    });  
});
```

I want to set a position for this dialog. I've tried changing `$(data).dialog();` to `$(data).dialog('option', 'position', [200,300]);`, but it doesn't work. How can I set it?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcTcf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
$(data).dialog({
    position: [200, 300]
});
```

The syntax `$(data).dialog('option', 'option-name', value)` is used for changing an option of a dialog that has already been initialized. But if you want to specify options at initialization time, you do so using a option object as the argument to the widget.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to api documentation for the [jQuery Dialog Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) and this [jQuery position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) will help you if you want more granular control of the position.

Comment: I've looked at that API, and I've tried to use it as I mentioned, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the selector incorrectly.

`$(data)` where `$data` is not a class or id, data is a string containing html.

Try `$("#dialog").dialog();` And then you surely would be able to figure it out with the API-documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
        if ($(this).hasClass('ui-dialog-titlebar-close')) return;
        event.preventDefault();        
        var data = '<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">';
            data += '<p>Hello.</p></div>';

        var options={
            position:[200,300]
        };

        $(data).dialog(options);
    });  
});
```

You can set 'option' like this